Como comparar 2 objetos e retornar uma propriade do segundo objeto que não está na comparação
tenho uma comparação para fazer entre duas listas, e para cada item encontrado, tenho que retornar uma propriedade da segunda lista, gostaria de fazer via LINQ, exemplo.
Tenho essa classe:
class Table
{
    private int hexToInt = 0;
    private string data = string.Empty;

    public int HexToInt { get => hexToInt; set => hexToInt = value; }
    public string Data { get => data; set => data = value; }

    public string Hex { get => hexToInt.ToString("X"); }
    public int HexSizeInBytes { get => Hex.Length / 2; }
}

Tenho uma lista desta mesma classe:
        List<Table> tableList = new List<Table>();
        
        Table table = new Table();
        table.HexToInt = 0;
        table.Data = "a";
        tableList.Add(table);

        table = new Table();
        table.HexToInt = 1;
        table.Data = "b";
        tableList.Add(table);

        table = new Table();
        table.HexToInt = 2;
        table.Data = "c";
        tableList.Add(table);

        table = new Table();
        table.HexToInt = 3;
        table.Data = "d";
        tableList.Add(table);

        table = new Table();
        table.HexToInt = 4;
        table.Data = "d";
        tableList.Add(table);

        table = new Table();
        table.HexToInt = 5;
        table.Data = "f";
        tableList.Add(table);

        table = new Table();
        table.HexToInt = 6;
        table.Data = "g";
        tableList.Add(table);

Também tenho uma matriz de char:
        char[] charArray = new[] { 'c', 'a', 'a', 'f' };

Eu gostaria de pegar cada item da matriz de char, procurar na lista de Table através da propriedade Data, e caso encontre uma correspondência, retorne o valor HexToInt. Esse retorno tem que estar em uma lista, exemplo da lista de retorno para os objetos acima:
Lista: [2, 0, 0, 5]
Tentei fazer isso, mas não funciona, porque a propriedade Hex fica inacessível nesse contexto:
var test2 = dteCharArray.Where(x => table.Any(y => y.Data == x.ToString())).Select(y => y.Hex).ToList();insira o código aqui


seria isso? charArray.Select(x => tableList.Where(y => y.Data == x.ToString()).Select(y => y.HexToInt).FirstOrDefault()).ToList()

@MarcosJunior, sim, isso mesmo! Obrigado! Por favor, coloca como resposta para eu escolher como solução.

Importante você [edit] sua pergunta reduzindo o código a um [mcve] do problema e explicar como tentou resolver, e descrever o mais objetivamente possível qual foi a dificuldade encontrada. Ao editar, automaticamente sua pergunta é destacada para uma revisão e a comunidade reavalia os votos e o fechamento. Queira consultar a [help] e respectivos links para um melhor entendimento da finalidade das perguntas e respostas do site.

Para ter o resultado esperado conforme o exemplo da pergunta:
var result = charArray.Select(x => tableList.Where(y => y.Data == x.ToString()).Select(y => y.HexToInt).FirstOrDefault()).ToList();

Porém, pode acontecer um resultado inesperado caso exista um valor em charArray que não corresponda a nenhum valor em tableList.
Se o charArray tivesse o valor { 'c', 'a', 'a', 'f', 'z' } e fosse utilizado o mesmo código acima, teria um resultado igual a [2, 0, 0, 5, 0].
Para não acontecer isso eu precisei assumir um valor jamais atribuido para HexToInt.
char[] charArray = new[] { 'c', 'a', 'a', 'f', 'z' };

var result = charArray.Select(x =>
{
    var r = tableList.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Data == x.ToString());
    /*
     * defini que -1 é um valor jamais atribuido para HexToInt
     */
   return r != default ? r.HexToInt : -1;
}).Where(y => y != -1).ToList();

